# Restler PHP API framework URL routing

Tags: php, api, rest

I have a question regarding the framework. I based my CRUD on your live example. I have this URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/test/index.php/api/t1/module1/username@mail.com?query1=mama&query2=papa
```

In my **api.php** file, I used GET method on this request:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->dp = new Control();
}

public function get($id=NULL, $id2=NULL, $id3=NULL, $id4=NULL)
{
    switch($id)
    {
        case "t1":
            return $this->dp->t1(func_get_args());
        break;
        case "t2":
            return $this->dp->t2(func_get_args());
        break;
        default:
            throw new RestException(400);
        break;
    }
}
```

Then on my **control.php**,

```
public function t1($numbers) {
print_r($numbers);
}
```

The response body of this is

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => t1
>       [1] => module1
>       [2] => username@mail.com
>       [3] => 
>   )

What I want to achieve in here is get the values of **query1** and **query2**? How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the following proof of concept and tested it and made sure it works!

```
<?php
class Api {
    public function get($id = NULL, $id2 = NULL, $id3 = NULL, $id4 = NULL, $query1 = NULL, $query2 = NULL) {
        return "$query1 $query2";
    }
}
```

For hosting the API above I use the following index.php (gateway)

```
<?php
require_once '../../restler/restler.php';
require_once 'api.php';
$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Api');
$r->handle();
```

When I call

```
http://restler2.dev/test/url_routing/index.php/api/t1/module1/username@mail.com?query1=mama&query2=papa
```

or

```
http://restler2.dev/test/url_routing/index.php/api/t1/module1?query1=mama&query2=papa
```

or

```
http://restler2.dev/test/url_routing/index.php/api/t1?query1=mama&query2=papa
```

I get

```
"mama papa"
```

So I should be able to pass it to another class another method easily

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't work Arul. What I do now is get the value from **$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']** but for me is not the best way to do it.

Comment: It works fine! I have tested and updated my example above with proof of concept. If this is not what you want, let me know